# auto increment in node-mongodb-native using counters collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, node-mongodb-native

Is there any way of implementing a [counters collection](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/#auto-increment-counters-collection) as described in the docs with node-mongodb-native?

I'm trying to avoid doing this by nesting over 9000 callbacks (which IMHO sounds untidy and not-elegant) but the good people who wrote this native driver refused to implement synchronous/blocking calls.

Does the native driver provide a someway to call user defined functions and use their return values during queries? Or could there be an alternate way of extracting a sequential count....maybe solely from an `ObjectID()`?

Any ideas?

**EDIT:** 
This is not for the `_id` field (That's taken care of by `db.coll.save(x)`)
I have different types of documents in a collection. Each of these needs its own "type serial" or "type sequence" if you know what i mean.

I've already implemented this (plus other stuff) with afew nested calls as shown bellow. `doc` is `JSON.parse`'d from the client. I have to return this `doc` to the client with an `_id` (sorted by `db.coll.save`) and with a `typeserial` (currently being sorted by `db.coll.count` as shown bellow)

```
 ///more nesting Async calls above. 
 db.collection('dox').count( { "type" : doc.type } ,
    function( err , count )
    {
        ///{some err checking code here}
        doc.typeseq = (1+count);
        db.collection('dox').save( doc ,
            function( err , doc )
            {
                ///{more code here}
                ///Finally return JSON.stringified doc with new info/members to client-side
            }
        );
    }
 );
```

I'd just like to know if there is a more elegant, anti-async way of getting my `doc.typeserial`

Comment: You only need two callbacks, one to get a predefined atomically retrieved _id and the other to actually insert your document. Once you have your auto increment _id it should always be unique to your inserted document this way

Answer (score 1):

I am basically going to slap my comment as an answer:

> You only need two callbacks, one to get a predefined atomically retrieved _id and the other to actually insert your document. Once you have your auto increment _id it should always be unique to your inserted document this way

To explain more, when you use `findAndModify` to `$inc` and return from the counters collection that `_id` should then be unique that the running of that script and so the consequental insertion of a document. Basically there would be no race condition in this method.

This does mean you will need some kind of parent function like `insertWithAI` which will do the first callback of using `findAndModify` to chain the latter callback of inserting but at the end of the day you should only need two callbacks.

Comment: I'm currently using `db.coll.count` to get my sequence, but in an async call. Check my edits above for further clarification (my bad on the ambiguity).

Comment: @Moje Ah that makes it a lot more complicated, however, these are not $inc fields so maybe there might be a way to call a `getSequentialId()` function hmmm

Comment: Touche! That's the tricky part now -> Implementing a persistent counters collection with a `getSequentialId(X)` function...Elegantly.

Comment: @Moje I did have an idea but it didn't pan out with async, I'll keep thinking

Comment: anyone found a solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I implemented auto-increment with the "optimistic loop" with the help of async whilst which worked fine:

[Creating incrementing numbers with mongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12350862/creating-incrementing-numbers-with-mongodb/30653123#30653123)