# Insert MAX(numberField) + 1 in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, insert, max

While insert a new document i just want to insert a field whose value must be `max(field) + 1.`
For eg
Something like this

```
db.test.insert({numberField : MAX(numberField) + 1})
```

Also if there is no document,1st document must have value 0 for numberField.After that increment1,2,3 like wise.

I dont want two queries one to find max number and other to insert incrementing that by 1.

Can anyone please help.Thanku

Answer (score 1):

There is plenty of stack overflow posts about how to create an auto-increment field in mongoose.

[auto-increment-document-number-in-mongo-mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14454271/auto-increment-document-number-in-mongo-mongoose)

[create-unique-autoincrement-field-with-mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23199482/create-unique-autoincrement-field-with-mongoose)

---

### @edtech

Here is a good example of auto-incremented fields implementation using Mongoose:

```
var CounterSchema = Schema({
    _id: {type: String, required: true},
    seq: { type: Number, default: 0 }
});
var counter = mongoose.model('counter', CounterSchema);

var entitySchema = mongoose.Schema({
    testvalue: {type: String}
});

entitySchema.pre('save', function(next) {
    var doc = this;
    counter.findByIdAndUpdate({_id: 'entityId'}, {$inc: { seq: 1} }, function(error, counter)   {
        if(error)
            return next(error);
        doc.testvalue = counter.seq;
        next();
    });
});
```

You should perform the Step 1 from [mongodb documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14454271/auto-increment-document-number-in-mongo-mongoose) firstly.

---

### EDIT - Soluce without mongoose - Aka MongoDB Native Driver

You can use the [mongodb native node.js driver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb) and implements one of the soluce explained in theses stack overflow posts:

[auto-increment-in-node-mongodb-native-using-counters-collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18372159/auto-increment-in-node-mongodb-native-using-counters-collection)

[Creating incrementing numbers with mongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12350862/creating-incrementing-numbers-with-mongodb/30653123#30653123)

Comment: Is it possible without using mongoose?

Answer (score 0):

There's no built-in command for that. Fetch this document and count the keys yourself.

Comment: Is there else anything i can do?